# How can i go to specific page of a website and fetch desired data using python and save it into excel sheet.this code need url till desired page

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

```
import requests from bs4 
import BeautifulSoup 
import xlrd file="C:\Users\Ashadeep\PycharmProjects\untitled1\xlwt.ashadee.xls" 
workbook=xlrd.open_workbook(file) 
sheet=workbook.sheet_by_index(0) 
print(sheet.cell_value(0,0)) 
r = requests.get(sheet.cell_value(0,0))
r.content soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser") g_data=soup.find_all("div",{"class":"admissionhelp-left"})
print(g_data)
text=soup.find_all("Tel") for item in g_data:print(item.text)
```

Comment: ello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to download an Excel file from the web and save it to your HDD?  I don't see any URL, but you can try one of these 3 ideas.

```
import urllib
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
urllib.urlretrieve(dls, "test.xls")


import requests
dls = "http://www.muellerindustries.com/uploads/pdf/UW SPD0114.xls"
resp = requests.get(dls)
with open('test.xls', 'wb') as output:
    output.write(resp.content)
```

Or, if you don't necessarily need to go through the browser, you can use the urllib module to save a file to a specified location.

```
import urllib

url = 'http://www.example.com/file/processing/path/excelfile.xls'
local_fname = '/home/John/excelfile.xls'
filename, headers = urllib.retrieveurl(url, local_fname)
```